# Rails 4 using Proc.new with conditions inside active record association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I created this association back when the project was using Rails 3. Since this we have upgraded to Rails 4 and now I am getting a deprecation warning about this. The following code is an example of what Rails 4 is saying is deprecated.

```
has_one :original_participant,
  :through => :original_participation,
  :source => :participants,
  :conditions => Proc.new {
    unless self.respond_to?(:organization_id)
      "original_participants_surveys_participants.organization_id = surveys_participants.organization_id"
    else
      "surveys_participants.organization_id = #{self.organization_id}"
    end
  }
```

The reason why the code has the unless condition inside the conditions block is due to sphinx. When sphinx is building it's indexes it will not have the organization_id available. When using the standard Active Record call it will have the organization_id. So I need to make this work both when it does and does not have the organization_id defined. I have done some research on this and so far have not come up with any solution for doing this the Rails 4 way. This still works fine in Rails 4 but again I keep getting the deprecation warning.

Long question short how do I convert this to be Rails 4 compatible without loosing the ability to check if organization_id is available?

Here is the actual warning message rails is giving me

DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your Surveys::Participant.has_one :original_participant declaration are deprecated: :conditions. Please use a scope block instead. For example, the following:

```
has_many :spam_comments, conditions: { spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
```

should be rewritten as the following:

```
has_many :spam_comments, -> { where spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
```

Comment: Can you post the exact warning message?

Comment: Sure posted it at the end of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
has_one :original_participant,
  ->(record) {
    unless record.respond_to?(:organization_id)
      where("original_participants_surveys_participants.organization_id = surveys_participants.organization_id")
    else
      where("surveys_participants.organization_id = #{record.organization_id}")
    end
  },
  :through => :original_participation,
  :source => :participants
```